# Regex to match string that's not contained in certain characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm attempting to replace certain parts of a string with regex in JavaScript, but only if they are not wrapped within `{{{` and `}}}`.

The system I currently have in place does multiple string replacements and wraps the replacements in these brackets. So therefore, if I was to replace "h" with the day of the week (let's say Thursday), the replacement would output `"{{{Thursday}}}"`. If the replacement was to happen again, the string would ultimately become `"{{{T{{{Thursday}}}ursday}}}"` as the "h" in Thursday has been replaced.

What I'm looking for is a regex pattern that would replace the "h" but only if it is not contained within the `{{{` and `}}}` wrappers.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

Here is some example code. Each replacement gets wrapped in the brackets, and regex patterns use (?!{{{) and (?!}}}) in an attempt to avoid past replacements.

```
var string = 'n d m y',
    dayTextRegex = /(?!{{{)n(?!}}})/g,
    dayRegex = /(?!{{{)d(?!}}})/g,
    monthRegex = /(?!{{{)m(?!}}})/g,
    yearRegex = /(?!{{{)y(?!}}})/g;

string = string.replace(dayTextRegex, '{{{Monday}}}');
string = string.replace(dayRegex, '{{{04}}}');
string = string.replace(monthRegex, '{{{June}}}');
string = string.replace(yearRegex, '{{{2012}}}');

//string is now equal to "{{{Mon{{{04}}}ay}}} {{{04}}} {{{June}}} {{{2012}}}"
```

Comment: Hi, it will be easier for us to help if you post your existing regular expression, sample input and expected output for given input.

Comment: I've updated my answer, seeing your posted code. Before I create a more complicated expression, please let me know if the current solution would work for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Just realized this won't work, but leaving it here for now until I can figure it out. It's interesting nonetheless :)

Mimicking the lookbehind and lookforward assertions in regex:

```
var str = '{{{h}}}';
str.replace(/({{{)?h(}}})?/g, function($0, $1, $2) { 
    return $1 && $2 ? $0 : '{{{' +$0 + '}}}';
});
```

Returns:

```
{{{h}}}
```

See also: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

**Update 2**

Seeing how you're using the expressions, I would use this construct instead:

```
string.replace(/[ndmy]/g, function($0) {
    switch ($0) {
        case 'n':
            return '{{{Monday}}}';

        case 'd':
            return '{{{04}}}';

        case 'm':
            return '{{{June}}}';

        case 'y':
            return '{{{2012}}}';
    }
})
```

Output:

```
{{{Monday}}} {{{04}}} {{{June}}} {{{2012}}}
```

This basically performs replacement without overlaps, so you don't have to worry about previously braced expressions.

Comment: Works perfectly! I never knew you could provide a function as the second argument in the replace function. With your solution, there's now now no need for the delimiters either. Thanks! :D

Comment: @DeanJames It's definitely useful sometimes :)